Cant push or commit to github repo using visual studio git
I set up my ssh and stuff, I set up my key and it shows as correct on github. When I cloned the repo it worked, but when I try pushing, nothing happens, and when I get:
Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
error: open(".vs/RWCollab/v17/Browse.VC.opendb"): Permission denied
fatal: Unable to process path .vs/RWCollab/v17/Browse.VC.opendb
Im using visual studios git, but i set up the key with regular git.
I dont even know where to start, I checked my keys and they all look fine.
